# Hiding the scroll bar in WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, scrollbar

I want to hide a vertical scroll bar in my WebView when I do not scroll the page. As for now, it is displayed always. I create a WebView programmatically, so my question is related to customization of the scroll bar programmatically. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`setScrollbarFadingEnabled()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScrollbarFadingEnabled%28boolean%29) method does exactly what you want. It hides scrollbar when the view isn't scrolling.

```
webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 63):

try this code,

```
webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for exactly this – to give the in-app experience, rather than an in-an-iframe experience.

Answer (score 48):

No need to change your Java code.
It will work if you put `android:scrollbars="none"` in your XML.

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
```

Answer (score 13):

Set `scrollbars` to `none` in the XML for WebView. For reference try this code.

```
<WebView android:id="@+id/webView"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:scrollbars="none"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

This is what you are after:

```
mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

For vertical scrollbar -

```
webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false)
```

For Horizontal scrollbar -

```
webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to other answers but to get a scrollbar that behaves like the one in ListView, this is the code:

```
webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true); // Explicitly, however it's a default, I think.
webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
```

Answer (score 1):

This finally worked for me:

```
mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.