# Strange white border on WebView while testing on HTC Sensation XE

Tags: android, webview

On HTC Sensation XE with Android 2.3.4 (and maybe on other HTC devices, unfortunately I can only on this one) there a strange white line on right border of the WebView (screenshot below). I've also tested my app on emulator with same params and on Asus TF101, **but everything was OK**.

[image: Here is the problem]

This layout is pretty complex to post here, so I've tested it on this one (and there is same bug too):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- This WebView created dynamically -->
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[And here is the page, that I'm testing on](http://kupitut.webtm.ru/index.php?longitude=10.0&lattitude=10.0&myLongitude=10.0&myLattitude=10.0). As you can see, there is no padding and no margin (`<body style="padding:0; margin:0;">`).

Can anyone give me an advice where the problem can be? Thanks.

Comment: Well i have experienced similar issue, i suspect it is default scroll of webView

Comment: @iNan wow, and how can I hide it?

Comment: May be this one  `webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);` can u try??

Comment: have you seen this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527899/disable-scrolling-in-webview

Comment: @sunil and don't want to disable scrolling itself.

Comment: @iNan, post it as new answer. Unfortunately I can check it only tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well i think you can use this `webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);`  to hide strange scroll bar. Hope it helps. Read this for more details [Hiding the scroll bar in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088826/hiding-the-scroll-bar-in-webview)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, was driving me crazy as SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY did nothing.  It turned out to be a box-shadow!!!!