# Hide scrollbar in webview - Titanium Android app

Tags: android, webview, titanium, scrollbar

I've an Android app in Titanium. In this app, I'm using a webview to display graphs. Once the webview has been loaded it displays for couple of seconds the webview scrollbars and then they automatically disappear. Is there a way to hide them for the all the time?

I'm using Titanium 3.2.2 SDK.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

yes check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088826/hiding-the-scroll-bar-in-webview) .

```
webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
```

or all the time :

```
webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I think native Android has this method, but I can't find it in Titanium. Is it possible to do it in Titanium? Thanks

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't read well your question. I don't have any idea... I hope you can find your solution. good luck :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
webView.showScrollbars = false;
```

or

```
webView.disableBounce = true;
```

Comment: showscrollbars only applies to mobile web and tizen and disableBounce to iOS.