# Hide scrollbar - Webview - CrossWalk

Tags: javascript, android, css, webview, crosswalk-runtime

How can I hide the scrollbars in the CrossWalk webview?

I've tried the following things:

- Applying this to the Webview layout XML

  `android:scrollbars="none"`
- Using javascript/css:

  ```
  document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  ```
- Everything suggested in this SO question: [Hiding the scroll bar in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088826/hiding-the-scroll-bar-in-webview)

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried any solution?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean? I've tried the things described.

Answer (score -1):

To disable scrollbars in webview, put the following instructions in the webview code:

```
WebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
WebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

In this way, the scrolling will work without the scrollbars.

Comment: I've also tried this (from the SO question I've linked to. It doesn't work). Can you confirm that it works for you with CrossWalk webview? (Because then I can start to look for whatever else might be causing this).

Comment: Never tried with CrossWalk. At this point, you need to verify why this scrollbar have been shown. Is it part of the webview or is it coming from Crosswalk?

Comment: I think it's default behavior for the CrossWalk webview. I'll take a look at it, and see if something pops up.

Thanks never the less. :-)