# Hide scrollbar in webview

Tags: javascript, android, css, android-webview

How can I hide the scrollbar on Android Chrome/Chromium using CSS/Javascript?

I've tried:

```
document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';
```

Which works on Chrome for Windows, but it doesn't seem to do anything for Androids Chromium backed Webview.

Comment: **[Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088826/hiding-the-scroll-bar-in-webview)**

Comment: Not a duplicate, since that is a question on how to do it in native Android code.
I'm using a custom webview which doesn't support these methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in CSS `overflow: auto;overflow-y: hidden;`

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It worked!!
I can only mark as answer after 7 minutes, will make sure to do it after that :-)